# Where OpenCSV creates the .csv files?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, directory, opencsv

I'm working with opencsv librarie in Eclipse and when I write something in a .csv I don't know in which folder is created. I should say that I need that the .csv file is not deleted when i turn off the app, so I can store in the assets folder, right?

My code is this:

```
try {
    String csv = "data.csv";
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

    //Create record
    String [] record = "hello,world".split(",");
    //Write the record to file
    writer.writeNext(record);

    //close the writer
    writer.close();

} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with opencsv, but rather with `FileWriter`.

Comment: also the android assets folder is read only once the app is packaged, so probably not there, no. Look into Context.openFileInput

Comment: `I can store in the assets folder, right?` **WRONG** You can only read from the `assets` folder, as well as from the `raw` folder. You are going to use the android file system. Provide a valid path, or the system will use its default path.

Comment: My guess is that you can find the file in the directory  getFilesDir().

Comment: @DerGolem sorry, I want to put "can't". And how can I provide a valid path? I know that normally the files are in the data/data/files folder, but it isn't there.

Comment: First that's not the right path, but how are you examining it anyway?  Normally internal storage contents are not readable by tools outside the app, except on unsecured devices or with the run-as tool under a debug build.

Comment: I'm looking the DDMS of Eclipse.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Answer (score 0):

**May be you can find it file at "/data/data/your_project_package_structure/files/data.csv"**

**Still don't find** the You can do like this. file.getAbsolutePath() gives you full path there you can identify where your file getting stored:

```
try
{
File file = new File("data.csv");

  // creates the file of name data.csv     
  file.createNewFile();

  //you can print absolute path of file
  System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

  // creates a FileWriter Object
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 

  //pass to csv writer
  CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

              //Create record
              String [] record = "hello,world".split(",");
              //Write the record to file
              writer.writeNext(record);

              //close the writer
              writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

Comment: The program with that goes to the catch and I don't know why.

Comment: Then add e.printStackTrace(); to the catch and log e.getMessage(). Also log file.getAbsolutePath(). It will not be writable. Look in the LogCat.

Comment: @Rubncin post your exception